# Customizing messages in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am quite new to omnet++, veins and SUMO.I am trying to send customized messages between RSU and the nodes. I am not able to understand how do I customize the message. When I want the message to be seen in the events log window while simulation.

I am tried to understand where the message string is in airframe11p.cc but I am not able to quite understand it. Where do I edit for displaying my own message?

Am I doing it wrong? Is there any other place I am missing to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send messages via OMNeT++ modules aka applications that are assigned to your agents implemented as Veins modules. So is the general schema. Take a look for example at the folder `src/veins/modules/application/traci`. Here you have a) a message file `TraCIDemo11pMessage.msg`, b) two modules`TraCIDemo11p.ned` and `TraCIDemoRSU11p.ned` as well as their C++ source files. In veins example you use `*.rsu[*].applType = "TraCIDemoRSU11p"`, here is the assignment happens. If you want to use a custom message with the same application, you should:

1. Create a new `.msg` file and define there your message fields.
2. Build your project to generate source code for a message file.
3. Change an application to work with your new message definition appropriately. Take a look at the lines *100-102* in `TraCIDemo11p.cc`:

   ```
       TraCIDemo11pMessage* wsm = new TraCIDemo11pMessage();
       populateWSM(wsm);
       wsm->setDemoData(mobility->getRoadId().c_str());
   ```

here you create your message object and fill all its fields with your data and then send it.